# AWS S3 Pricing for fetching images in a mobile app

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-dynamodb

can someone explain me [AWS S3 pricing](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/pricing/?trk=936e5692-d2c9-4e52-a837-088366a7ac3f&sc_channel=ps&sc_campaign=acquisition&sc_medium=ACQ-P%7CPS-GO%7CBrand%7CDesktop%7CSU%7CStorage%7CS3%7CCA%7CEN%7CText&s_kwcid=AL!4422!3!536324434071!e!!g!!s3%20pricing&ef_id=CjwKCAjwmJeYBhAwEiwAXlg0AW8bqxj3BBJ5NU6wvQ35TnZbw05ml8tTND8qSCeEmoUj377eizmKXBoCVusQAvD_BwE:G:s&s_kwcid=AL!4422!3!536324434071!e!!g!!s3%20pricing), I am not sure to understand correctly.

Basically, I have a react-native mobile app that has images in it.
I took AWS S3 as an option to host and fetch images from there.

In the app, I am displaying images using [S3Images](https://docs.amplify.aws/ui/storage/s3-image/q/framework/react-native/) component, which means that for each images, on each render, it will query a network call to fetch and display the image.

Details :

- Average size of an image : 0.00015 GB
- The app will contain approximately 100gb of images
- A user will approximately fetch up to 10,000 images (GET request) per month
- Let's say there are 1,000 users per month using the app

Calculations :

- Hosting 100gb per month : $0.023 per GB * 100GB = 2.30$ / Month
- 10,000 images (GET requests) * 1,000 users = 10 millions of GET requests
- 10 millions GET requests * 0.00015 GB = 1500GB
- **1500 GB * $0.09 per GB = 135$ USD / Month ?????**

Does my calculation makes sense or am I wrong?
If so, does anyone has alternatives?

Comment: Seems correct. You can get 1TB free [if you use CloudFront](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/aws-free-tier-data-transfer-expansion-100-gb-from-regions-and-1-tb-from-amazon-cloudfront-per-month/).

Comment: You forgot S3 API costs, though it only adds $4 to your costs.

Comment: Well what bother me is that 135$, it's way too expensive for such a basic thing like reading pictures from a server... is there any alternative or way's to reduce that cost? I thought caching images but it wouldn't make sense to cache 10k images on user side...

Comment: If a lot of the images are re-used, it could be a good candidate for caching. CloudFlare would be cheaper than Amazon CloudFront.

Comment: What is your thoughts on Digital Ocean? It seems 90% more cheaper than Amazon S3 for the same usage as above, has anyone worked with them?
https://www.digitalocean.com/pricing/spaces-object-storage